# After setting ssh key still get asked for password from github

Tags: git, github

I setup my ssh key on my ubuntu production machine. As I am using the server for another project I know that the key is already properly connected to github.

When doing `ssh -T git@github.com` I get a success message, however I still get asked for a password. Even after providing it once I still get asked:

```
root@ubuntu:/var/www/project# ssh -T git@github.com
Hi user! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
root@ubuntu:/var/www/project# git pull
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

Any suggestions why?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: It is not clear how you cloned the repository onto your system. Did you use `git clone <ssh-url>` or https/downloaded the zip? I suspect you used one of the last two methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your local repo config is still using the `http` mechanism, you need to switch it to the ssh one.

Standing in the main folder of the local copy, edit the `.git/config` file (with `vim .git/config` or using the editor you like)

Under the tag `[remote "origin"]` you will see the `url` attribute. It should be pointing to a `http` reference of your repo.

Comment or delete that line and switch the URL to point to the ssh reference as illustrated below:

```
[remote "origin"]
   url = git@github.com:user/repo.git
   #url = https://github.com/user/repo.git
```